Creating a mask for a specific node inside a Geometry Node system
I'm trying to make a very basic Geometry Node setup, and need some randomisation in the rotation.
Though, i only need the randomized rotation in a specific area, while keeping the rest straight
I created a Vertex group to isolate the parts that i want not to be affected but i can't find a way to use said vertex group as a mask for a couple of nodes.
Here's my setup :

Pretty basic. I want to use the mask on the "Haircards rotation" nodes.
I was thinking of using the "Mix" node to separate two areas, while A would go into "Haircards rotation" as a value of 1, B would go in the Vertex Group as a value of 0, but i'm missing something here.
Would you guys have an idea on how to make it work or any workaround ?
Thanks !

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

You almost got it. Your Mix node is in Non-uniform mode, switch it back to Uniform and the top vector will be a factor. Plug your vertex group to this factor. To do this add a Named Attribute node and select your vertex group.

Additionally you can change the mix node type to Rotation.
If your vertex group has only 0 or 1 you can also use the Switch node instead of the Mix node.
